# How to get the expression of matching capture in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, matching, capture

In Perl, how can I get the expression of a capture that has matched in a regex?

```
$s = 'aaazzz';
$s =~ s/(a+)|(b+)|(c+)/.../;
$s =~ s/(?<one>a+)|(?<two>b+)|(?<three>c+)/.../;
```

I mean the expression (e.g. `a+`), not the string `aaa`.

I need the expression of both numbered and named captures.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that automatically. What are you trying to do that needs this?

Comment: I have a regex with many pipes. Depending on the regex matching I want to call different subs afterwards.

Comment: You can tell which part matched by whether the match is in `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.

Comment: I know how to determine which capture has matched (defined $1), but to get the expression I have to analyze the whole regex ( (a+)|(b+)|(c+) ). Isn't there a special variable that stores the last matching expression?

Comment: Why do you need to get the expression? Don't you know what you put into the regexp? If `defined $1` then the expression is `a+`, if `defined $2` then the expression is `b+`, etc.

Comment: But if I have a regex with let's say 1000 alternatives I have to check on average 500 to know which one has matched. If I knew the expression I'd less code to write. I have all the expressions in a hash to start the corresponding sub then.

Comment: the thing is, there can be many expressions that matched. Most regexps are not just a single set of alternatives, there can be multiple alternatives in different groups, e.g. `(a|b)(c|d)`. Returning just the last matched alternative would not be very meaningful for this. And if it were `(a|b)(a|c)`, and it said you matched `a`, you wouldn't know if it was the first `a` or the second one.

Comment: I need to know the definite capture that has finally matched not the string (`a`). I need know if `(a|b)` or `(a|c)` has matched. -- In my case there are no overlaps between the capturing expressions, and if there were I would need the leftmost.

Comment: I know what YOU need. I'm just trying to explain why Perl doesn't have it, because it needs to be more general.

Comment: Thank you. I think this negative report is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @regexes = (
    qr/(a+)/,
    qr/(b+)/,
    qr/(c+)/,
);
my $string = 'aaazzz';
foreach my $re(@regexes) {
    if ($string =~ $re) {
        print "Used regex is $re\n";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Used regex is (?^:(a+))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assemble your regex from components and then test which groups matched. For demo purposes, I have only used match and not match and the replace operator 's', but same principle applies.

```
$s = 'aaazzz';
$part1 = '(a+)';
if ( $s =~ /$part1|(b+)|(c+)/ ) {

    if ($1) {
        print("$part1 matched\n");
    }
    else {
        print("$part1 did not match\n");
    }
}
```